# Shell script not running with cron tab

Tags: shell-script, cron

My shell script is not running using cron tab. If I execute this script using `sudo ./myscript.sh`, everything works.

`myscript.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! cd /var/www/myfolderapps/myfolderapp; then
  echo 'Failed to cd to /some/dir' >&2
  exit 1
fi

mv cms/configs/database.json ./
mv cms/configs/options.json ./
mv cms/configs/analytics.json ./
mv cms/sql/patchs.json ./
mv cms/public/uploads ./
mv cms/node_modules ./

rm -rf cms
git clone git@gitlab.com:****/myproject.git
mv myproject cms

rm -rf ./cms/configs/database.json
rm -rf ./cms/configs/options.json
rm -rf ./cms/configs/analytics.json
rm -rf ./cms/sql/patchs.json
rm -rf ./cms/public/uploads

mv ./options.json ./cms/configs
mv ./database.json ./cms/configs
mv ./analytics.json ./cms/configs
mv ./patchs.json ./cms/sql
mv ./uploads ./cms/public
mv ./node_modules ./cms

cd cms

node sql/index.js

node scripts/mergeOptions.js

rm -rf ./tasks
rm -rf .bowerrc
rm -rf .eslintrc.json
rm -rf .gitignore
rm -rf .scss-lint.yml
rm -rf bower.json
rm -rf changelog-template.hbs
rm -rf CHANGELOG.md
rm -rf gulpfile.js
rm -rf README.md

cd ../

/usr/local/bin/pm2 restart process.json

exit;
```

My app is running into another folder :

```
Cloning into 'myproject'...
DEPRECATION WARNING: The logging-option should be either a function or false. Default: console.log
[PM2] Applying action restartProcessId on app [myfolderapp](ids: 0)
[PM2] [myfolderapp](0) ✓
┌─────────────────────────┬────┬──────┬──────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬───────────┬──────┬──────────┐
│ App name                │ id │ mode │ pid  │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem       │ user │ watching │
├─────────────────────────┼────┼──────┼──────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼───────────┼──────┼──────────┤
│ myfolderapp │ 0  │ fork │ 5236 │ online │ 137478  │ 0s     │ 0%  │ 15.3 MB   │ root │ disabled │
└─────────────────────────┴────┴──────┴──────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴───────────┴──────┴──────────┘
Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
```

Comment: Any error messages sent to the specified email address or logged elsewhere? Is the script executable? Does it try to use environment variables that are not available? Could you say something about what the script is doing and what you expect it to do?

Comment: I dont receive any emails and if I execute the script with the command `sudo ./rupdate` in my folder `/var/www/website` everything works.

Comment: What Kusalananda said. Also, change your crontab to this: `0 4 * * * /var/www/mywebstite/rupdate.sh 2>/tmp/cron.log` then check if the file `/tmp/cron.log` is created and, if so, see if there are any error messages there.

Comment: Why are you setting `HOME` to `/`? First why are you setting `HOME` at all, is it needed? And second, if it is needed, shouldn't that be root's home directory, `/root`?

Comment: If I remove the `HOME` declaration, I recieve the email. So the issue is probably about this declaration ?

Comment: Is is really webs**t**ite ?

Comment: @tonymx227 we can't know this since you don't show your script so we have no idea what it is doing. What I can tell you is that it doesn't make sense to set HOME to `/`.

Comment: It may well make sense to set `HOME` to `/` (or to any other directory path) under some circumstances, but we can't see the effect that this has in your script as you don't show it.

Comment: I updated my post with the entire script and log that I recieved this night.

Answer (score 1):

Your script appears to assume that it is executed with a particular directory as its current directory. Make sure that the current directory is set appropriately at the start of the script by using `cd`.

For example, if the `cms` directory is located in `/some/dir`, then use something like

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if ! cd /some/dir; then
    echo 'Failed to cd to /some/dir' >&2
    exit 1
fi

# rest of script goes here
```

This would terminate the script with a diagnostic message if the `/some/dir` directory does not exist or if the current user can't `cd` into it for whatever reason.

If your `git` command (or any other utility) needs to access files in the user's home directory (for e.g. authentication), then setting `HOME` to a directory which is not the user's home directory would make that command fail or fail to work in the expected way.  The `HOME` variable is typically already set correctly when executing cron jobs, and seldom have to be modified.

If you are required to modify the `PATH` variable to find the `git`, `node`, or `pm2` commands (or any other non-standard command), then I would do so in the script itself rather than in the crontab.  Setting `PATH` in the crontab would modify the `PATH` for *all* cronjobs scheduled by that tab, which in many cases may not be wanted.

Judging from the last line of your error output, at least the `pm2` command can't be found in the default `PATH`, so adding the directory where `pm2` is located to `PATH` would be necessary.

Your script also appears to expect that the `cms` directory exists, and it obviously tries to move some configuration files from it to a new checkout of the directory from some Git repository.  It's unclear what you expect to happen if the `cms` directory is not found, or why you don't just do an `git up` in the `cms` directory.

The Git repository that you check out is called `Gestiaweb`, but the script expects a directory called `Website`. It's unclear whether these names are related or if `Website` is a pre-existing directory.

Comment: Ok so now, my cron tab works but the script seems not working as expected. If I run the script manually it works but with `crontab`, I get an error. See edit. My cms seems to be deployed on another directory and not in the `/var/www/cms/WEBSITEFOLDER` directory.

Comment: Hello, I updated my post to be more clearly.

Comment: @tonymx227 It appears as if you have modified your question in such a way that my answer now is irrelevant.  Instead of doing that, what I would suggest that you do is to roll back the question to the state where it contains the error log, and then ask a completely new followup question. I think this would be best as your follow up question is totally separate from your initial question.